# Error translation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a piece of some translation file:

```
errors:
  format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
  messages: 
    too_short: "must be greater then ..."
```

I want that my 'too_short' message must show message with length value from Active Record validation rule. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
errors:
  format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
  messages: 
    too_short: "must be greater than %{count}"
```

Comment: It's correct, but you should change #{count} to %{count} and I'll mark your answer as correct!